# Swift - UITextView does not display text

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitextview

My `UITextView` does not display its `text` and I have no idea why.

```
let linkLabel: UITextView = {
    let v = UITextView()
    v.backgroundColor = .clear
    v.text = "Link"
    v.textColor = .lightGray
    v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext", size: 18)
    v.font = v.font?.withSize(18)
    v.textAlignment = .right
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()
```

It was a `UILabel` before and working perfectly fine. But I need it to be a `UITextView`. However if I change it to `UITextView` like in the code the text is not getting displayed.

Any idea why that happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your UITextView frame is equal to CGRect.zero and unlike a UILabel, a UITextView does not have an [intrinsic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622600-intrinsiccontentsize) frame. That's why you don't see it.

---

**Solution**

1. Use init(frame: CGRect)

---

```
UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30))
```

2. Set a frame property later

---

```
let v = UITextView()
v.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30)
```

**Important:**

The linkLabel have to be added to the view via InterfaceBuilder or in code with a method view.addSubview of the UIView object

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(linkLabel)
}
```

**Debug techniques:**

- Debug View Hierarchy

Click the [Debug View Hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH9-SW2) button in the bar at the top of the debug area to inspect a 3D rendering of the view hierarchy of your paused app

[image]

Comment: 3. Create constraints for UITextView

Comment: I added `v.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30)` inside my declaration but it is still not showing? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @DieGlueckswurst check the `Important` in the answer.

Comment: I am doing that. Like I said, if I just change `UITextView` to UILabel` everything works perfectly fine

Comment: I am using it inside a `tableViewCell` so I call `contentView.addSubview(linkLabel)`

Comment: @DieGlueckswurst Inspect your cell with "Debug View Hierarchy" button

Comment: I already did that and it is not being displayed at all. I just added `v.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30)` among all the other assignments inside the code above. Is that wrong?

Comment: Update your question with 1. more code from `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` 2. What are you setting up in InterfaceBuilder

Comment: ... It is showing now. I restarted Xcode and now it is displayed like you would expect it... Thanks for your help man. And sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

You can use  sizeToFit() and isScrollEnabled to false like below:

```
let linkLabel: UITextView = {
        let v = UITextView()
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        v.text = "Link"
        v.textColor = .lightGray
        v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext", size: 18)
        v.font = v.font?.withSize(18)
        v.textAlignment = .right
        v.sizeToFit()
        v.isScrollEnabled = false
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
// And set the frame whereever you want 
linkLabel.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
self.view.addSubview(linkLabel)
```